# Onload-Event do not stop on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, svg, onload

I have an problem with androids (my device has 4.1.2) native browser and androids chrome. I build a HTML5 webapp with SVG and the onload event. I included the SVG like this (and recomanded by the W3C)

```
<object id="svgContent" data="file.svg" onload="MyMethod();">
    Your browser did not support SVG
</object>
```

My JS function looks like this

```
function MyMethod() {
    $('#svgContent').attr('style', 'display:none;');
    var iIntervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
        $('#svgContent').attr('style', 'display:block;');
        clearInterval(iIntervalID);
    }, 100);
}
```

My problem is, that the onload event is triggerd by the modification of the display-style attroibute and so it is a calling loop (event fires all the time). The desktop version of chrome and firefox did not have this strange behaviour. Did anybody have an idear how to solve this?

For those how will ask, i want to reshow the SVG after loading, to rescale the svg to full width of the container. By default, the svg has the size of his own viewbox and a width and height of 100% did not work (only absolut values work, but this is not responsive design). Hiding and showing fix this problem on desktop browsers, but causes discribed problem on android. Perhaps, you have any other idear, how to bring the SVG to full width without my "hack".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `clearInterval` before setting `display:block`? It's probably not impossible that it takes some time to redraw the svg on a mobile device, and it's entirely possible that since you use `setInterval` that the callback will get called again before the `display:block` update is complete.

You could also use `setTimeout`, which will not repeatedly get called every X milliseconds.

You should also be aware that changing `width`, `height` or `display` like this will normally cause page reflows, which can hurt performance a bit on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not possible to use onload-functions on SVG under Android (had a similar problem some minutes ago). What you can and should do is the following:

Edit the SVG in a text editor and add something like this to the inital -tag:

```
width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
```

Make sure to edit the viewbox with the right dimensions. I don't know for an  insertation, but if you use , this will work fine.